# Is Ubuntu 18.04 section "InRelease" Mandatory?

Tags: debian, ubuntu-18.04

we are using our local debian repo with a freight. Now we trying to deploy packages for Ubuntu 18.04. Seems that our current freight version doesnt create "InRelease" section. **Is it mandatory?** When we tried to search the deployed package from some Ubuntu 18.04 machine, we couldn't find the package and when trying to run:

```
apt-get update
```

we got an error:

```
The repository 'http://[our_repo]/Debian/apt-repo bionic InRelease' is not signed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should wait until 18.04.01. It should appear soon!